# monkeypatching proxies with an async request library

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, proxy, request, monkeypatching

I've been using the trio/curio asynchronous libraries for a while now as a easier/more human replacement to the more complex asyncio python library. Trio is really a great library, but that misses one thing: a HTTP request library like aiohttp.

Now there is one async HTTP library that's made to work with trio and curio, and that library I have been getting used to for over two years now is called [asks](https://github.com/theelous3/asks)

asks is great for pretty much everything I do (a part from a few missing features and bugs) but it's lacking one major element: Proxy support.

Indeed the asks library has no support for HTTP or SOCKS proxies, and that's something I really want to be able to use.

Now here's the issue, the lack of proxy support has come up in asks developpement since as early as 2017, and it has been on the dev's (theelous3) todolist since then, but after 2 years of developpement, after proxy pull-requests have been opened and closed, after numerous emails with contributors and the dev promising that proxy support is still on their todolist and they just need to find the time to work on it, I'm starting to realise that it's just not going to happen any day now.

Now I'm unable myself to make a pull-request adding proxy support, I don't have the knowledge to do this kind of thing yet, and while I could use the aiohttp library that does support proxies, I already built my whole async system around trio and I do not want to rebuild everything around the (p in the a) library that's asyncio just so that I can send requests with proxies.

Now I've been reading up a bit on monkeypatching, and I was wondering if they're would be anyway I could somehow monkeypatch the asks library to use proxies in its requests. During my research I came across [PySocks](https://pypi.org/project/PySocks/) with this example on monkeypatching the default requests library:

```
import urllib2
import socket
import socks

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "localhost")
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

urllib2.urlopen("http://www.somesite.com/") # All requests will pass through the SOCKS proxy
```

Now this is nice, but as the PySocks disclaimer says:

> Note that monkeypatching may not work for all standard modules or for all third party modules, and generally isn't recommended. Monkeypatching is usually an anti-pattern in Python.

So I'm left wondering, would there possibly be a way to monkeypatch async requests made by the asks library so that they pass through proxies? I'm guessing the answer is probably not, but I'm currently stuck in a rut and maybe stackoverflow can provide more help and answers to my issue.

I'm really stuck in a tough situation: Do I either remake my whole async-await system using asyncio even though I really don't like that library and really fell in love with trio just so that I can send requests using proxies?

Do I just give up on proxies all together?

I'm actually really considering saving up a bit of money to actually pay a profesionnal to work on the library and add proxy support to asks.

Comment: Does something like this work for you? https://github.com/HyperionGray/starbelly/blob/933be1cc186a882ceb1142f560ff2d0079b3174b/starbelly/downloader.py